# Can I run chrome package app from JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to run installed chrome package app from my webpage. How can I do this? Is there any public API in chrome to do this?

Comment: Is your packaged app available as an extension as well?

Comment: @AdamJeffers No, my package app is only a package app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I use a url_handlers. It can run app from matched url.